# Выборка связанных данных yii2

Tags: yii2

У меня есть модель практический занятий пользователя и модель автомобилей. В модели занятий поле **auto** связано с **id** в модели авто. Для того, что бы при выводе занятий я мог легко выбрать данные авто, я в модели занятий написал такое:

```
public function getAuto()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Autos::className(), ['id' => 'auto']);
}
```

И при выводе использую так:

```
var_dump($model->auto)
```

Но ничего не выводится. Я что то делаю не так? Извините, если плохо объяснил

Comment: это я натупил, спасибо вам за помощь. дело в том, что у меня же поле auto, и метод тоже auto, и вызывая $model->auto я получал не объект auto, а только его id. сменил на getAutos() - все работает

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу сам, может кому то пригодится: методы, для получение связанных данных не должны называться так же, как поля. В моем случае, у меня есть поле **auto** и метод **getAuto**, который я вызываю как

```
$model->auto
```

тем самым получая не связанные данные, а только их id